# Boolean to String

Tags: magento2, grid, ui

I have made admin grid as UI component.

I've got boolean column called status in db.

This is where I show column value.

```
<column name="status">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

For now it displays only '1' or '0'.

What I want to achieve is to display Yes or No instead of 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array to associate value with label :
in your grid.xml add

```
<column name="status">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status</item>
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
             <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
             <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Status</item>
             <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
             <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
             <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
         </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Then Now Create Status.php at

`app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status.php`

```
 <?php

 namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

 class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
 {
     /**
      * Options getter
      *
      * @return array
      */
     public function toOptionArray()
     {
         return [['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Yes')], ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('No')]];
     }
 }
```